# Foreach and querys performance improvement issue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, iteration

I'm having a problem with performance in my code.

The method below is used to create a comparative score of companies from the whole country based some rules:

```
public List<object> GetCNAEBRCycleChart(int VisitId)
    {
        List<object> result = new List<object>();


        Visit visit = Context.Visit.Find(VisitId);
        Company company = visit.Company;
        var CNAE = company.MainEconomicCNAE.IdentifyCNAE;

        string[] Themes = new string[5];

        Themes[0] = "Finance";
        Themes[1] = "Market";
        Themes[2] = "Organization";
        Themes[3] = "Planning";
        Themes[4] = "People";

        int count = 0;

        List<Visit> listVisitCNAECountry = (from vis in Context.Visit
                                            where vis.Company.MainEconomicCNAE.IdentifyCNAE.StartsWith(CNAE)
                                                && vis.Order == 1
                                             select vis
                                                ).ToList();

        double[] Values = new double[5];

        Values[0] = 0;
        Values[1] = 0;
        Values[2] = 0;
        Values[3] = 0;
        Values[4] = 0;

        foreach (var vis in listVisitCNAECountry)
        {
            count = 0;
            var visitIdCompany = vis.Id;

            var diagnostic = Context.Visit.Find(visitIdCompany).Diagnostic;

            if (diagnostic != null)
            {
                foreach (var itemTheme in Themes)
                {
                    var TemaAux = itemTema;
                    int QtQuestion = (from itemForm in Context.FormItem
                                        join tipo in Context.FormItemType on itemForm.FormItemTypeId equals tipo.Id
                                        join itemForm2 in Context.FormItem on itemForm.FormItemParentId equals itemForm2.Id
                                        join itemForm3 in Context.FormItem on itemForm2.FormItemParentId equals itemForm3.Id
                                        where itemForm3.Name == TemaAux && tipo.Name == "Pergunta"
                                        select itemForm
                                              ).Count();

                    var sumAnswerCompany = (from alter in Context.Alternative
                                            join itemForm in Context.FormItem on alter.FormItemId equals itemForm.Id
                                            join itemForm2 in Context.FormItem on itemForm.FormItemParentId equals itemForm2.Id
                                            join itemForm3 in Context.FormItem on itemForm2.FormItemParentId equals itemForm3.Id
                                            join answer in Context.Answer on itemForm.Id equals answer.FormItemId
                                            where answer.AlternativeId == alter.Id &&
                                            answer.DiagnosticId == diagnostico.Id && itemForm3.Name == TemaAux

                                            select alter.Value
                                    ).AsEnumerable().Sum();

                    double scoreCompany = //Some calculations

                    Values[count] += scoreCompany;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        count = 0;

        foreach (var val in Values)
        {
            Values[count] = //more calculations
            count++;
        }

        var model = new { NameCategory = "CNAE in Country", Value1 = Values[0], Value2 = Values[1], Value3 = Values[2], Value4 = Values[3], Value5 = Values[4] };

        result.Add(model);

        return result;
    }
```

The problem is that, with the actual CNAE, the list listVisitCNAECountry gets 16000+ elements, which make for terrible performance.

In my localhost environment it's taking 30min+ and I don't even know where to begin to actually improve the performance.

The biggest problem is that I really need all those iterations to make the calculations right.

If anyone has any ideas, please, help me.

Comment: If your code works but you need a performance improvement suggestion, it's better to post a question on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Also, are you querying from a DB ? have you tried benchmarking the queries only on the DB, to see if the actual C# work is causing perf issues, or maybe the poor performance on DB queries themselves?

Comment: I believe there are a few areas that improvements can be made IMO. I feel that you're making too many context calls and I also feel that you're pulling too much information when you do, then relying on the cached data to get results. One such is ```.Sum()```.  You should use break points in VS and check each step to see where the largest bottleneck is but I have a feeling it's just a mixture of all of it. In VS you should be able to see the time between break points in MS's and this can help you narrow down where part of the issue is at.

Comment: I have tested every query and the DB is Ok.

Comment: Now I will be working with these issues with some seniors at my company. 

All of the comments here brought a real light to the problem, so I thank everyone for the help.

When I finally solve it will come back with the updates on the answer.

Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to change is:

```
                var sumAnswerCompany = ( /* complex query */
                                ).AsEnumerable().Sum();
```

This is bad; instead of issuing `select sum(...)` as a database query, it instead will have to select the column(s) and return all the rows required, which may be a *huge* amount of bandwidth.

Instead, do the sum at the database and just bring back one number:

```
                var sumAnswerCompany = ( /* complex query */
                                ).Sum();
```

However, frankly I'd suggest writing the entire thing in raw SQL using joins and grouping from the original data. Sometimes LINQ isn't your best tool.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII ADO.NET is not "slower than Linq" - that's an absurd statement. LINQ providers like EF and L2S sit *on top of* ADO.NET; they cannot be *faster* than the tool they're using - which is ADO.NET. Now, if you're *exceptionally lucky*, it will take no measurable time to parse the expression tree, compare it to the model configuration (entity/storage), and generate a query, and if you're even luckier the query will be halfway decent. But for a complex scenario like this, that sounds unlikely. So LINQ will be *at best* "as good", but most likely: much worse than well-written SQL.

Comment: Is the use of pure sql in this particular case better?

Comment: @LucasHipólito in my opinion: absolutely. That should be written as a single SQL query that starts with whatever inputs you need for the top loop, using whatever combination of CTEs, nested queries, or sub-queries; then presumably a "group by" sum so you get back one single grid with a row per company / sum pair. It is *very* hard for me to show the SQL without your database, though...

Comment: @MarcGravell I've retracted my comment.  I got it backwards and apologize. However; I do still feel this is a suggestion and not necessarily an answer; at least not a full answer.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I don't disagree; I'd love to post a fuller expansion of what that would look like, but it is virtually impossible without direct SSMS or similar

Comment: @MarcGravell i will try the pure sql today and then i come back here to say the results. thanks

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, the pure sql approach made it better. Still not optimal, but now i get help from some seniors of my company, so I believe in little time I come back with updates